# How can I fix the segmentation fault error in C language on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

In my C program, I'm trying to change the gecos field of my password file which contains **/etc/passwd** records. At first, the user should enter the account name and the program should find the gecos field of the entered account name, then if the size of the gecos field is bigger than 0, the program should ask the user to enter the new gecos field. Then, if the size of the new gecos field and the old gecos field are equal, it should update it, but I guess I have a problem with the `gec=malloc(strlen(pw->pw_gecos)+1);` part because I get segmentation fault error. How can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

My codes are below:

```
struct passwd *pw;
struct passwd *pwd;
char *gec;

printf("Enter the account name: "); 
scanf("%s", &sItem); 

if ((pw = getpwnam(sItem)) == NULL) {
    printf("getpwnam: unknown %s\n",
           "passwd.idx" );
    exit(0);
}

if ((pw->pw_gecos = malloc(strlen(pw->pw_gecos)) + 1) == NULL) {
    puts("error");
    return 3;
}
int sz = strlen(pw->pw_gecos);

printf("Account name: %s\n", sItem);
printf("Size of the entered GECOS field: %d\n", sz);

if (sz > 0) {
    printf("Update the gecos field: "); 
    scanf("%s", &gec);
    if (strlen(gec) == sz) {
        //pw->pw_gecos = pwd->pw_gecos;
        gec = malloc(strlen(pw->pw_gecos) + 1);
        //gec = pwd->pw_gecos;

        printf("Gecos field is updated successfully!");
        printf("Updated GECOS field: %s\n", pwd->pw_gecos);
        //gec = pw->pw_gecos;
    }
}
```

Comment: malloc for `gec`  is allocated after that is being used `scanf("%s", &gec);` `scanf("%s", &gec);` should be just `scanf("%s", gec);`

Comment: I only got this far: 'scanf("%s", &sItem);'.   No declaration for 'sItem' shown.

Answer (score 1):

`pw->pw_gecos = malloc(strlen(pw->pw_gecos)) + 1)` overwrites the pointer set by `getpwnam()` with one that points to uninitialized data.

The rest of the code has undefined behavior when you try to read the string `pw->pw_gecos`.

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve as you only posted a code fragment with missing context and definitions.